# listing of all Apache virtual hosts in one place

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm working on a big web application which uses Apache 2.2 with a complicated configuration of virtual hosts that are defined in many distributed vhost.conf files which are then included into httpd.conf.

Is there any simple and quick way of listing out all of the various virtual host configurations in one place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running [httpd -S](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html) will show you the defined VirtualHosts.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a listing of all active virtual hosts along with what port and name they run on and what line of what config file they can be found on by using the status operator on the apache init scripts:

```
service httpd status
```

If your distro doesn't include that option in the init scripts, you can call it manually using

```
/path/to/httpd -t -f /path/to/main/config
```